# WordPress doesn't catch 404s in PHP AppEngine

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

Following the [**official tutorial**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress), Installing **WordPress 3.5.2** was successful but the installation is not handling 404 errors. All the non-existing pages show up the homepage.

Eg. `http://localhost:8080/not-found-1/`, `http://localhost:8080/not-found-2/`, etc. show the same thing what `http://localhost:8080/` shows.

How do we fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked on local installation. I will update when I deploy on GAE Servers.

1. Open the Wordpress Installation ie. `http://localhost:8080`.
2. Go to ***Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks*** or `http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`.
3. Under ***Common Settings***, select anything except ***Default*** or add your own structure in ***Custom Structure***.