# App Engine, Wordpress 404 Handling

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I've read a number of topics on here about App Engine's handling of 404 errors when you deploy on wordpress. I am experiencing issues with every bad URL returning 200 OK, and serving the homepage.

In the local development environment, using the App Engine launcher, 404 errors work as I'd expect them to. I don't understand how this earlier topic fixed the issue: [WordPress doesn't catch 404s in PHP AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472917/wordpress-doesnt-catch-404s-in-php-appengine) but I have of course tried what was suggested.

I am running Wordpress 4.0-alpha.
There is a 404.php file, in the theme (of course, it works locally)

Realise it might not be easy to give a solution, however even some pointers on how I can start debugging this would be greatly appreciated. The logs don't return anything useful.

Thanks for your time.

Anthony

Comment: The current WP 4.0 build is [Beta 4](http://wordpress.org/news/2014/08/wordpress-4-0-beta-4/), you should be running this, not an alpha build. If 3.9.2 functions normally, you've just found a bug. You should submit a ticket on [make.wordpress.org](http://make.wordpress.org/core/reports/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will update this. I have actually isolated the issue slightly, if I disable the App Engine plugin it works. I will update Wordpress later on today and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Keep in mind, any time you're running a build that says "alpha" or "beta" in the name, this is software that's still being actively developed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WordPress doesn't catch 404s in PHP AppEngine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472917/wordpress-doesnt-catch-404s-in-php-appengine)

Comment: Ok, I've upgraded to 4.0-beta 4 and the issue still exists, though it appears to be an issue with the plugin and not Wordpress.

Comment: In addition to the comments above, I have investigated this a little further and have isolated the problem to the core.php file within the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that commenting out line 59 in the core.php file seems to fix the issue

```
//$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = $PHP_SELF = preg_replace( '/(\?.*)?$/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

Not sure what that will effect as a consequence though.